# MongoDB - I can't find the filesize of my database

Tags: mongodb

Strangely, on MongoDB 3.0.3 standalone server, after running a db.stats() command on a database I only get this output which is not showing information about the filesize of my database except for non existing ones :

```
> use MyBase
switched to db MyBase
> show collections
XmlCache
system.profile
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "MyBase",
        "collections" : 2,
        "objects" : 62228,
        "avgObjSize" : 139963.13608022113,
        "dataSize" : 8709626032,
        "storageSize" : 3128832000,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 9,
        "indexSize" : 15106048,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.runCommand({ dbStats: 1, scale: 1 })
{
        "db" : "MyBase",
        "collections" : 2,
        "objects" : 63765,
        "avgObjSize" : 138065.89466007997,
        "dataSize" : 8803771773,
        "storageSize" : 3129327616,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 9,
        "indexSize" : 15286272,
        "ok" : 1
}
> show dbs
ABase                     0.035GB
AnotherBase               0.036GB
MyBase                    2.929GB
local                     0.000GB
> use dummy
switched to db dummy
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "dummy",
        "collections" : 0,
        "objects" : 0,
        "avgObjSize" : 0,
        "dataSize" : 0,
        "storageSize" : 0,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 0,
        "indexSize" : 0,
        "fileSize" : 0,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Running the same command on either a 2.6.9 or 3.0.3 server in a replicaset with the same database will get me much more informations and I don't understand why (and it bothers me as I need that information for some scripts) :

```
rs0:SECONDARY> use MyBase
switched to db MyBase
rs0:SECONDARY> show collections
XmlCache
system.indexes
system.profile
rs0:SECONDARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "MyBase",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 127225,
        "avgObjSize" : 36730.40902338377,
        "dataSize" : 4673026288,
        "storageSize" : 6541684736,
        "numExtents" : 24,
        "indexes" : 9,
        "indexSize" : 49333984,
        "fileSize" : 55741251584,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 52,
                "totalSize" : 45903593184
        },
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
rs0:SECONDARY> show dbs
ABase                           0.078GB
AnotherBase                     0.453GB
MyBase                         51.929GB
local                           6.075GB
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

Where is that filesize information hiding ?

Comment: `"dataSize" : 4673026288 and "storageSize" : 6541684736` give the information you need, right?

Comment: Not really, datasize, storagesize and filesize are 3 differents informations. Before compacting the storagesize can be equal to the filesize

Comment: In fact for wiredTiger `fileSize = storageSize + indexSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbStats.fileSize`

> Only present when using the mmapv1 storage engine.

[Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/).

Comment: Damn, I didn't see it despite having read the page beforehand. I'll need to find another way now

Comment: To those interested : `fileSize = storageSize + indexSize`